# Finding the integral of $\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} dt.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking for the integral of $\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} dt.$

My work:

Dividing the $\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)}$, I get $2 + \frac{-16t^2 -2t + 9}{4t^3 + 8t^2 + t + 2}$ or $2 + \frac{-16t^2 -2t + 9}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)}$

Using the partial fraction decomposition on the expression $\frac{-16t^2 -2t + 9}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)}$, the partial fractions of $\frac{-16t^2 -2t + 9}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)}$ I get 
is $\frac{-3}{t+2} + \frac{-4t + 6}{4t^2 +1 }$

So...I conclude that....

$$\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} = 2 + \frac{-3}{t+2} + \frac{-4t + 6}{4t^2 +1 } $$

Getting now the integral of $\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} dt$.

$$\int \frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} dt = \int \left( 2  + \frac{-3}{t+2} + \frac{-4t + 6}{4t^2 +1 } \right) dt $$
$$ = \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t + 6}{4t^2 +1 } dt $$
$$ = \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t}{4t^2 +1 } dt + \int \frac{6}{4t^2 +1 } dt $$
$$  = 2t  - 3ln(t+2)  - \frac{1}{2}ln(4t^2 + 1) + 6\arctan (2t) + C$$
$$   = 2t  - \left( (ln(t+2)^3)  + ln((4t^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}) \right) + 6\arctan (2t) + C$$
$$   = 2t  - \left( ln((t+2)^3(4t^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}) \right) + 6\arctan (2t) + C $$
$$   = 2t  - \frac{1}{2}\left( 2\left( ln((t+2)^3(4t^2 + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}) \right)\right) + 6\arctan (2t) + C $$
$$   = 2t  - \frac{1}{2}ln((t+2)^6(4t^2 + 1))  + 6\arctan (2t) + C $$

But in my book, it says that the integral of $\frac{8t^3 +13}{(t+2)(4t^2+1)} dt$ is $2t  - \frac{1}{2}ln((t+2)^6(4t^2 + 1))  + 3\arctan (2t) + C$
My answer is so close to that of the book, but I couldn't locate my error. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is $(\arctan(2t))'$?

Comment: @choco_addicted   $\int \frac{6}{4t^2 +1 } dt = 6\arctan(2t)$. It came from the integral  $\int \frac{du}{u^2 +a^2}  = \frac{1}{a}\arctan(\frac{u}{a})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that
$$
\int \frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=\arctan t + C.
$$
Thus, let $u=2t$, then
\begin{align}
\int \frac{6}{4t^2+1}dt &= \int \frac{6}{u^2+1}\frac{1}{2}du\\
&=\int \frac{3}{u^2+1}du\\
&=3\arctan u + C\\
&=3\arctan 2t + C.
\end{align}
Thus $\int \frac{6}{4t^2+1}dt = 6\arctan (2t) + c$, you found, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you should properly pose x=2t but then dx/dt=2

$I= \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t}{4t^2 +1 } dt + \int \frac{6}{ \color{red}{4t^2 +1 }} dt$

$I= \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t}{4t^2 +1 } dt + \int \frac{3}{ \color{red}{x^2 +1 }} dx$

$I= \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t}{4t^2 +1 } dt + 3\int \frac{1}{ \color{red}{x^2 +1 }} dx$

$I= \int 2 dt  + \int \frac{-3}{t+2} dt + \int \frac{-4t}{4t^2 +1 } dt + 3\color{red}{\arctan(2t)}$